# How to map a mess of ActiveRecord relations into a single ActiveRecord::Relation object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Basically, I want to take a typical group of ActiveRecord relations and make it look like a single, simpler relation.

Suppose I have the typical `Post`, `Comment`, `User` where a post has many comments and comments have a user.

Now, suppose I want to get the following data into a view. (Assume all the data needed can be read via a single Arel statement).

```
post.title
post.tag.name
post.comments.last
post.comments.last.user.full_name
```

I would like to just access them via a new object called PostSummary via the following methods:

```
post_summary.title
post_summary.tag_name
post_summary.last_comment
post_summary.last_comment_user
```

So far, not too tricky. It can be done via an OpenStruct and some mapping, but I would like PostSummary to be a read-only ActiveRecord::Relation object that allows you to do the following:

```
PostSummary.first.attributes #=> [title, tag_name, last_comment, last_comment_user]
PostSummary.count #=> 42
...
```

I'm sure this is possible with a lot of work, but is there something already setup to do this?

Comment: What do you expect `PostSummary.count` to be a count of? Post records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems kinda messy to do what you're suggesting. I'd recommend dropping these methods in a decorator. Decorators are often used to hold information and methods that are relevant for the view to avoid bloat on your models.

For a good decorator library see [Draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper).

Comment: I'm digging around Draper a bit, but at first glance, it appears to be exactly what I want.